# jquery - Add upload field not displaying file name

Tags: jquery

I've been struggling to figure a way to make a styled `input type="file"` and I finally got it. But then I ran into another problem which is IE8 multiple file support. So I figured I could put an add field button. However, I ran into another problem once again. The file would display on the first field but the second one doesn't show the name of the file. Here I have a working demo on JSFiddle

http://jsfiddle.net/933rp/

Answer (score 0):

For some reason `.on()` only binds the event to currently existing elements, so you have to add the event listener again every time you add a field, see [working demo](http://jsfiddle.net/933rp/1/)

EDIT: you are not binding the event correctly, the above way works but here is a better way [link](http://jsfiddle.net/933rp/2/);

basically use `$(document).on('fileselect','.btn-file :file', function (event, numFiles, label) {...}` to bind the event

Answer (score 0):

You're using `delegation` everywhere, but on this bit.

Replace this:

```
$('.btn-file :file').on('fileselect', function (event, numFiles, label)
```

With this:

```
$(document).on('fileselect', '.btn-file :file', function (event, numFiles, label)
```

So the event handler will be attached to every element added later on.

Demo: http://jsfiddle.net/933rp/3/